# Usage of "voted in"

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Is it correct to write *voted in* in the following sentences?

> - Members may vote in a new leader.
> - Board members will be nominated and voted in by the team.

Comment: Yes, but only after the election. I would correct it to _and voted **on** by the team_. Unless it is known in advance who the board members will be, and the team's voting is strictly a formality.

Answer (score 2):

Both of those examples appear grammatically correct. The common usage of the compound "to vote in" is more frequently and naturally used in the form "to vote ... in." That said, ending a sentence in a preposition is to be avoided, so one usually follows "to vote ... in" with what position or office the object is being elected to.

In the case of your first example, that would be:

> Members may vote a new leader into office.

And in the case of your second example, because it is clear that board members are voted into the board, I would opt for the active voice instead of changing the format of "to vote in":

> The team will nominate and vote in board members.

That said "to vote in" is most frequently used when one intends to specify what position the object is being voted into. If the electee is the main focus and the position is understood, "to elect" is more straightforward and natural.

E.G.:

> Members may elect a new leader.
>
> Board members will be nominated and elected by the team.

Comment: Prepositions are perfectly acceptable words to end sentences with. But leaving that aside, to *[vote in](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vote_in)* is a phrasal verb as with *call in*, *opt in*, and so forth— the *in* is not a preposition at all, in contrast to *in* as in *I voted in the mid-terms* or *I voted in the farthest booth from the window*.

Answer (score 0):

> *[This answer was written before the question was edited. The original version of the question had both sentences on a single line as if they were intended to be read one after the other, whereas the question format now shows them bulleted as two independent sentences. Most of what I've written below still applies, but, with the revised question format, certain points are now moot.]*

In British usage, retaining the current wording I would have written:

> Members may vote ***for*** a new leader. Board members will be nominated and voted ***on*** by the team.

although, in fact, I would probably have reworded it.

I agree with John Lawler's comment that ***voted in*** is best used *after* the election, as it means ***voted into office***.

I would agree with the first and third suggestions by RedVillian, but would suggest

> The team will nominate and vote ***for*** board members.

in place of his second suggestion; and, in place of his fourth suggestion,

> Board members will be nominated and ***a new leader*** elected by the team.

In fact both the original suggestion, and RedVillian's second (and fourth?) suggestion are grammatically incorrect:

> Board ***members*** will be ... voted in by the team.
>   The team will nominate and *vote in board **members***.

There is only ***one*** new leader, so only ***one*** Board member can be voted ***in***.
Additionally, in the light of the first sentence "*Members may vote in a new leader*, "it seems that "*Board members*" and the "*team*" both refer to the same group of people, thus adding to the ambiguity.  I think what is really meant (if 'the team' and 'Board members' are the same people) is:

> Board members may nominate candidates for a new leader, and then vote for one of the candidates.

Although the original could have meant (if 'the team' is different from the 'Board members') :

> The team will nominate and vote for new Board members. *(plural)*
>   The new Board members *(plural)* will then nominate and vote for a new leader *(singular)*.

Summarising:

> Electors vote (based) ***on*** a list of candidates.
>   An elector votes ***for*** a candidate
>   A *winning* candidate is voted ***in*** by his supporters. (He is voted ***into*** office.)
>   A *losing* candidate *who currently holds the position* is voted ***out*** (*of office*).