# Upvote vs. Vote up

Tags: word-usage

On StackExchange sites I usually use *upvote*. Elsewhere - *vote up*. What is the better variant - *upvote* or *vote up*? Is it context-specific?

Comment: It really doesn't make a dime's worth of difference.

Comment: Use *upvote* as a noun, *vote up* as a verb. That should be a consideration to the reader.

Comment: @Kris: I don't buy that. *I will not vote up your comment* sounds decidedly stilted to me, even if I can't *downvote* it.

Comment: If you simply say "vote (for)," we'll know what you mean on this site.

Comment: @robusto how many ELU questions are like that?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can vote your comment up, not down. You don't buy, you get it free :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we have here was originally just a compound verb, similar to *vote in* which has a question devoted to it here:

[Usage of "voted in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113912/usage-of-voted-in?rq=1)

But what happened on Stack Exchange is that the common compound verb became lexicalized - instead of remaining a compound of two words, it became a single word, *upvote*, as both a noun and a verb. This often happens when compound phrases (which tend to be relatively long) are in very common usage. People will contract and abbreviate, and these new forms stop behaving as abbreviations, and become lexical terms themselves.

So both *vote up* and *upvote* are common here on Stack Exchange. Outside Stack Exchange, where the concept of upvotes and downvotes isn't so prevalent, using the verb *upvote* might be met with a raised eyebrow.